# Why is my bot saying that server owner is None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Alright so I want the bot to say who is the server owner, but it said that the current server owner is "None". Is there a way to fix this problem?

Code:

```py
guild = ctx.guild
embed = discord.Embed(timestamp=ctx.message.created_at, color=discord.Color.dark_green())
embed.set_thumbnail(url=guild.icon_url)
embed.add_field(name="Members", value=guild.member_count)
embed.add_field(name="Region", value=guild.region, inline=True)
embed.add_field(name="Owner", value=guild.owner, inline=True)
embed.add_field(name="Created", value=guild.created_at, inline=True)
embed.add_field(name="Channels", value=len(guild.channels), inline=True)
embed.add_field(name="Roles", value=len(guild.roles), inline=True)
embed.add_field(name="Boosters", value=guild.premium_subscription_count, inline=True)
embed.set_author(name=f"{guild} | ID: {guild.id}", icon_url=guild.icon_url)
embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you enable the [Gateway Intents](https://discord.gg/PMRCF3gT)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect your issue comes from the new Discord Privileged Gateway Intents. You can read more about them in [this page](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#intents-primer) of the discord.py docs.

To fix your problem, I'd try the following. First, enable the Members privileged intent on your Discord application by going to `https://discord.com/developers/applications/<app_id>/bot` and checking "Server Members Intent".

Then, use the Members intents in the following way:

```py
import discord

intents = discord.Intents(members=True)
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

# The remainder of your code...
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> If `fetch_offline_members` is set to `False` then the user cache will not
> exist. This makes it difficult or impossible to do many things, for
> example:
>
> Computing permissions
>
> Querying members in a voice channel via VoiceChannel.members will be
> empty.
>
> Most forms of receiving Member will be receiving User instead, except
> for message events.
>
> **Guild.owner will usually resolve to None.**

To get around this you might want to set your client with the additional option:

```
 discord.Client(*, loop=None, fetch_offline_members = True)
```

Another method you can try to inspect is `guild.owner_id` in case it is related to the issue [here](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/2472).

Comment: Where should i place this `discord.Client(*, loop=None, fetch_offline_members = True)
` at?

Comment: Post your whole code, the particular part is used to initiate the connection with Discord.

Comment: Whole code? My code has 4000+ lines. Can you provide me an example? Thanks.

Comment: The documentation has it all really. Also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Alright, I placed the code correctly, but it still doesn't work. Any ideas?